# Null checker fails C#

Tags: c#, error-handling, claims-based-identity

My null checker fails, whats wrong here ?

I am trying to check if the user claims does exist for the variable sID which is just the staffID of the postback model

So I added a try catch statement to stop it crashing

```
  var sID = ViewModel_CreateNewAgent.Tbl_Brands_Staff.BranchStaffID.ToString();
  var staffIDExists = _context.AspNetUserClaims.Where(c => c.ClaimValue == sID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

                    /// VALIDATE STAFF ID
                    var claimsExists = await _userManager.GetClaimsAsync(user);
                
                    var doesStaffIDExist ="";
                    try
                    {
                        doesStaffIDExist = staffIDExists.Result.ClaimValue ?? doesStaffIDExist;
                        //doesStaffIDExist = staffIDExists.Result.ClaimValue != null ? staffIDExists.Result.ClaimValue : doesStaffIDExist ;
                    }catch(Exception err) { }
```

Comment: `staffIDExists` can be null, `staffIDExists.Result` can be null (less likely), also ClaimValue is a string so it can be "", why don't you set a breakpoint and check...

Comment: What do you mean by "my null checker"? What do you mean by "fails"?

Comment: its a user sign up page which checks to see if the SID exists, if it doesnt. It returns null, hence crashes the code. I want to check if null then assign nothing or zero to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use `try-catch` for normal workflow, try to fix the real problem.

Here `staffIDExists` and/or `staffIDExists.Result` and/or `ClaimValue` could be `null`. Use the [null conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) `?` to make your code safe and readable:

```
var staffIDExists = _context.AspNetUserClaims.Where(c => c.ClaimValue == sID).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
string doesStaffIDExist = claimsExists?.Result?.ClaimValue ?? "";
```

However, does that code make sense? The `Where` checks for `c.ClaimValue == sID`, so `doesStaffIDExist` is always either `""`(if there is no such claim) or `sid`.

> I am trying to check if the user claims does exist for the variable
> sID

Well, then this code would be easier:

```
return _context.AspNetUserClaims.Any(c => c.ClaimValue == sID);
```